# Fried garlic turning black

Tags: frying, garlic

When frying garlic in olive oil, it usually turns translucent after a while. This time, it quickly turned black. Why? Was the pan too hot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

garlic burns very easily and is very smelly when it does.

If you are just sauteing then you should cook at a relatively low temperature and take it off the heat as soon as it is translucent.

If you are toasting the garlic then leave it on and watch it closely. Stir often and take it off when it is just golden.

If it burnt very quickly then I would agree with you that your pan was too hot.

Comment: It also turns very bitter when burnt.

Comment: @hobodave: I noticed!